# <img> loading attribute lazy load doesn't work for local images

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, electron

I'm trying to implement lazy loading logic for images on my Electron desktop app. I wanted to use the `<img>` element with loading attribute to [lazy load images](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/); But, I noticed that it only works for remote image; If I tried to set the src to a local image with file://imagePath, The local image still gets loaded right away.
For example:

```html
<img loading="lazy" src="file:///myImage" width="466" height="466" alt="">
```

Can we still use this img loading attribute for lazy loading local images? If not, how should I implement lazy loading logic for images in Electron app? I'd appreciate any suggetions!

Comment: don't know the implementation of adding `loading="lazy"` attribute to image in electron. But usually we remove the src of image attribute that we want to lazyload... and by intersection observer, we add the image src when the img element is to be visible in UI. If you stick to this basic, your local images will also lazyload. But I dont understand, why would you want to lazyload any local image.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try to dynamically populate the `src` attribute to see if that works for me. The reason, why I want to lazyload local images, is I am trying to render a lot of, like 5k, local images on my Electron app. I need some lazyload logic for increasing performance.

Comment: just found out `loading="lazy"` is a browser feature... https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/. but not sure how it has been implemented. I see lots of images are loaded before DOM load, images that are much below the visible fold: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/img-loading-lazy. Try out the javascript way, this is very reliable: https://web.dev/lazy-loading-images/#images-inline-intersection-observer

Comment: I can confirm that this is happening in Electron. I'm just not sure why. Almost makes me want to dig into the Chrome source code.